# Ubuntu 16.04 boots to desktop background, keyboard doesn't work

Tags: 16.04

I did a new install of Ubuntu Desktop. After I login, it boots to only the desktop background and a mouse. I cannot enter the terminal because right clicking with the mouse does nothing, and <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> or <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>t</kbd> do nothing.

I've tried following along with similar threads on this issue, but they all seem dependent on the keyboard or mouse working.

Additionally, sometimes it will repeatedly flash a notice about WiFi networks available, or flash an error about some sort of internal service error.

Comment: I have the same problem. Have you fixed your problem?

Comment: No, I could not figure it out so I installed Cinnamon instead which works fine for my purposes (I do nearly all my work in a VM).

Answer (score 1):

I've encounter the same problem today but my keyboard was working. But I can suggest you to try following things:

1. Try to connect another keyboard.
2. Maybe right click works. Have you try that ?
3. Try to boot on Ubuntu Live cd. Normally it let will you reinstall (depends on how you've organize your files but it may be a solution).
4. If you had ssh on your Ubuntu 16.04 (normally yes) and have another PC (Linux is best), you can with ethernet connect them.

Then try to know which IP are near you(try: `nmap -sP 192.168.1.0/24` on the another PC)... Normally not so much. Try to find which is good one or get their hostname (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/657482/how-to-find-host-name-from-ip-with-out-login-to-the-host).

After that, try to connect via ssh (If you have ssh on your Ubuntu).

```
ssh user@ip_adress:/home/user
# Or
ssh user@hostname:/home/user
```

On Windows you have Putty to make easily ssh connexion.

If you recover keyboard or a terminal, try several link on web who propose to solve problem: `ubuntu just mouse and wallpaper`.

None of these links has solved my problem, but I make another thing:

I remove and reinstall `lightdm` because it won't start. After, I simply do the following steps (Becarefull, you'll loose all preferences and settings in your programs if you do this steps, but it's essential.):

1. Add a new user and connect with him.
2. If that's working (sidebar, menu comes back), back up file of old user (without any `.*` folder, like `.config` !! Just data.)
3. Delete old user. And remove his home (`sudo rm -Rf /home/old_user`)
4. Reboot: `sudo reboot`
5. Create once again your user as you like.

Good luck !